# How to remove <p></p> tag from the string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string as follows:

```
<p>Message Pilcrow</p><p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>
^^^               ^^^^
```

I need below string as result:

```
Message Pilcrow<p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have tried below code..

Regex.Replace(yourstring, "^.*?", "")

but i got result as

    <p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>

Removed Message Pilcrow complete section.)

Comment: Read [ask] and explain very explicitly what the format of your input string is. You're showing an example, not a format. Is the input string always exactly this? Or can the three parts differ? Can there be other parts of the string? Is the first part always enclosed in `<p></p>`? Are there always other parts? And so on. The reason your question is unclear is the reason you're getting wildly varying code thrown at you in answers, which **will** break in one case or the other.

Comment: Hi, 
 Is the input string always exactly this?

Ans: this string is actually a message which can contain any text in any format. users can send even website content as well and it will always enclosed with this p tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
string yourstring = "<p>Message Pilcrow</p><p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>";
Regex rgx = new Regex("<p>|</p>");
string res = rgx.Replace(yourstring, "", 2);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Here, **'2'** indicates the number of times the replacement occurs.

This will give the following output as expected:

```
Message Pilcrow<p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>
```

*See MSDN: [Regex.Replace(String, String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
   string msg = "<p>Message Pilcrow</p><p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>";
   String res1 = msg.Replace("</p>", ";");
   string res2 = res1.Replace("<p>", "");
   string res3 = res2.Replace("<br/>", "");
   String[] arr = new string[3];
   arr = res3.Split(';');
   string res = arr[0].ToString() + "<p>" + arr[1].ToString() + "</p><br/><p>" + arr[2].ToString() + "</p>";
```

Result return:

```
Message Pilcrow<p>Testing....</p><br/><p>testing in progress...</p>
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer, explain what it does. It also seems hopelessly convoluted and not robust.

Comment: Just im trying to help.. why dont you try to run the code before you decided to downvote.

Comment: It's bad code. It involves a lot of unnecessary string operations, and will break for any other input. What if the input contains `test<br/>ing` and they want to preserve that `<br/>`?